# asp.net c# search function in several xml files

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, search

I have an several XML files and i want to create an search function, for instance if the user search for "Information System" or just "System" it will find the specific project and display it.
There are 20 XML files and i am not allow to change the structure of the XML files. i started to write the search function, but i don't sure how to continue.

buttons aspx code:

```
<asp:TableCell>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="filterTB"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="search" />
</asp:TableCell>
```

particle example of XML :

```
<project>
    <name>Shema Information System</name>
    <type>Information System</type>
    <faculty>IE</faculty>
    <year>2013</year>
    <customer>
        <name>Shema association</name>
    </customer>
    <students>
        <groupCode>igroup28</groupCode>
    </students>
</project>
```

aspx.cs code:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = filterTB.Text;

    string[] textArr = text.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n', ',' });
}
```

Comment: How exactly file being an XML is important? Based on what you have written you can simply do string.Contains on these 20 text files.

Answer (score 0):

You may proceed with following way:

1. Loop thru all the xml files by using Direcoty.GetFiles()
2. Read the "name", "type" etc nodes and compare their value with your
   textArr
3. When you find a match, add that file in a list, and show it to users.

Hope this helps!